# JApplet - get images from FTP

Tags: java, ftp, carousel, japplet

I have the following JApplet (basically a carousel of scrolling products images).

```
private void populateMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            images.add(ImageIO.read(new URL(getCodeBase()+"/images/"+(i+1)+".jpg")));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JAppletExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above method I a adding images (currently located in a package inside my solution) to and ArrayList of Images to be displayed in the carousel.

Now how can I make the images available on FTP so that the iamges can be changed via FTP?

(Note: images inside my packages are saved as 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg)

Comment: This could be a violation of the Applet security policy, I'd check that first

Comment: this is for a school assignment so I seriously doubt that!

Comment: Makes no difference, the applet security is defined by the security policy on the local PC